# Define another macro inside __using__

Tags: macros, elixir

I have a module called Interfaces:

```
defmodule Interfaces do
  defmacro __using__(module) do
    @module unquote(module) |> List.first |> elem(1)
    defmacro expose(name) do
      IO.inspect params, label: "Expanding macro with: "
      IO.inspect @module, label: "I need this !!"

      def unquote(name)() do
        IO.puts "The function has been created with exposed name"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Another module called Interfaces.MyModule :

```
defmodule Interfaces.MyModule do
  use Interfaces, for: Something.DefinedElseWhere

  expose :plop
end
```

But at compile time I get

```
** (CompileError) lib/my_module.ex:6: undefined function expose/1
```

Comment: What is the point of this? You are already inside a macro, why not just define a regular function? As for the actual question, I have no idea if this is supposed to work.

Comment: I edited my example so you would understand the point, It should define a function with the name passed in the `expose` params

Comment: Why not just create that macro then instead of going through `__using__`?

Comment: because I need the options passed in the use statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend that you read the [Macros Guide](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/macros.html) on the official Elixir website. While what you're doing is possible (using `quote`), it is not encouraged at all.

Macros should be simple and their functionality should be broken down further in other macros and methods if the need arises. **One way to do that is to use the `import` statement** in your macro to import other macros that you need exposed in the final module:

```ex
defmodule Interface do
  defmacro __using__(opts) do
    quote(bind_quoted: [opts: opts]) do
      import Interface

      @interface_module Keyword.get(opts, :for)
    end
  end

  defmacro expose(name) do
    quote do
      IO.inspect @interface_module, label: "I need this !!"

      def unquote(name)() do
        IO.puts "The function has been created with exposed name"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Now you can use it:**

```ex
defmodule MyImplementation do
  use Interface, for: AnotherModule

  expose(:hello)
end
```

---

<sup>*Here's [another example](https://github.com/sheharyarn/memento/blob/2d88b26070767efed883e72a5d3193fdf5027ff2/lib/memento/table/table.ex#L113-L140) from one of my projects, on how you should break down the implementation of large macros using helper functions and other macros.*</sup>

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Didn't want to have `expose` public in the Interfaces module but I can live with it though. Thanks !

Comment: You can also specifically call `import Interface, only: [expose: 1]` and/or have a separate undocumented `Interface.Definition` module with the `expose` macro and import it from there.

Comment: Another way to ensure the user calls `use Interface` first is to use [Compile Callbacks](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html#module-compile-callbacks).